# Function that prints without capital letters in Python

Tags: python, function, capitalization

I'm trying to write a simple function that takes a string and returns a string without the capital letters that were in the original string. I have looked at tons of other posts with questions similar to mine but most of them approach this on a skill level that I yet can't comprehend due to lack of knowledge.

This is what I have come up with.

```
def no_capitals(string):
    result = []
    for char in string:
        if not char.isupper(): result.append(char)
    return (result)

print(no_capitals("X007XK"))
print(no_capitals("Xmen R cute"))
```

The desired output for this would be:

```
007
men cute
```

However, this function to no surprise returns this in list form.

```
['0', '0', '7'] 
['m', 'e', 'n', 'c', 'u', 't, 'e']
```

So I'm guessing I will have to approach this in a different way. My knowledge of Python is very limited, so I don't have a lot of "tools" to work with. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: return ''.join(result)

Comment: @balderman this is not a comment but an answer.

Comment: @balderman It worked! your comment should def be an answer. I used 3 hours to google for a solution that you gave me with 3 words. Closing 23 tabs. Thank you!

Comment: Extending on his approach, the whole funciton can be done in a single line: `return ''.join(char for char in string if not char.isupper())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `''.join()`:

```
def no_capitals(string):
    return ''.join(char for char in string if not char.isupper())


print(no_capitals("X007XK"))
print(no_capitals("Xmen R cute"))
```

Output:

```
007
men  cute
```

Comment: You don't need the `[` and `]`, and I think that will be a bit more performant.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `+=` instead of `append`. If you use append you add char to the list and not concatenate the result with the next char and in the result you return list with characters.

```
def no_capitals(string):
    result = ""
    for char in string:
        if not char.isupper(): result += char
    return (result)

print(no_capitals("X007XK"))
print(no_capitals("Xmen R cute"))
```

More efficient possibility is using .join() function. So look below.

```
def no_capitals(string):
    result = []
    for char in string:
        if not char.isupper(): result.append(char)
    return "".join(result)

print(no_capitals("X007XK"))
print(no_capitals("Xmen R cute"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ''.join and removing upper letters, it works (thanks dan1st for the comment below).

```
strs = "X007XK"
results = ''.join([d for d in strs if not d.isupper()])
output: '007'

strs = "Xmen R cute"
results = ''.join([d for d in strs if not d.isupper()])
results
'men  cute'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, **[including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) really helps to improve the quality of your post**. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the structure you created and changing only the minimum amount of code you could do this:

```
def no_capitals(string):
    #result as a string
    result = ''
    for char in string:
        #if the character is not uppercase add it to the end of result
        if not char.isupper(): result += char
    return (result)

print(no_capitals("X007XK"))
print(no_capitals("Xmen R cute"))
```

now gives:

```
007
men  cute
```

Note: there are two spaces between men and cute

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "X007XK"

caps_omitted_string = filter(lambda c: not c.isupper(),string)
```